# decimal part missing after calculation

Tags: sas

I need to calculate daily average units.

```
proc sql;
select sum(Units) as TotalUnits, count(distinct(Date)) as Days
from a1;

/* Output */
TotalUnits Days
700        31
```

Then the result should be `700/31=22.5806451612`

But if I calculate by

```
proc sql;
select sum(Units)/count(distinct(Date)) as AvgUnits
from a1;

/* Output */
AvgUnits
22
```

Its decimal part got truncated. How could this happen?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127558/sql-divide-by-two-count  You're dividing two Integers, you'll need to cast them to Decimals.

Comment: This doesn't happen with a trivial example.  Please provide an example that replicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in SAS you can apply a format to solve this.

```
proc sql;
select sum(Units)/count(distinct(Date)) format=Best12. as AvgUnits
from a1;
```

Comment: I couldn't recreate the error personally, but this is the best answer

Comment: This isn't terribly likely to help, unfortunately, unless there are more details missing.